# How to separate the legend and hist in tmap of R?

Tags: r, tmap

I want to let hist in other position.But I can't find any function in tmap to do it.

```
library(tmap)
data(World, land)

tm_shape(land, ylim = c(-88,88)) +
  tm_raster("elevation",
            title = "Global Land elevation",
            legend.hist = T)+
  tm_shape(World) +
  tm_borders(col = "black")+
  tm_layout(scale = .8,
            legend.position = c("left","bottom"),
            legend.bg.color = "white", legend.bg.alpha = .2,
            legend.frame = "gray50")
```

[image]

Comment: I do not think this is possible (yet).

Comment: This is a sad reality.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add the argument `legend.hist.z=4` where 4 stands for "lower right".

Comment: It only moves histogram in relation to the rest of the legend (not to the other part of the map).

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately.